# How do I create a custom RMB in Linux to execute python script

Tags: python, linux

Background: Coming from windows, where I had created a couple of small C# programs I could execute from right mouse button on folders. Have since moved to Linux (completely new) and I would like to be able to do something along those lines. Also beginning to learn python hence the combo. Script will be used to manipulate the folders and files within the folder clicked.

So I guess I have three questions:

1. How do I add a custom RMB accessible from clicking on folders?
2. How do I get that to execute a python script? (googling got me as far as adding the following line at the top of the script might be a way to go: "#!/usr/bin/env python3", so maybe just point out the location of the script is enough and that line tells it to execute using python3)
3. How do I pass the folder name or folder location in as a parameter to the script and how to access it in the script?

*Edit...
Assuming the RMB could execute something like "python3 my_script.py 'something' 'something else'" I have figured out how to catch those somethings within my_script.py. So if I'm not way of on this I'm mostly interested in questions 1 and 2.

Comment: I think you need to explain what "RMB" means.

Comment: The answer to (1) depends entirely on which desktop environment (gnome, kde, something else...) you are using (and, even in cases where that is possible, each environment is probably going to have a completely different solution).  [This](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/91876/is-it-possible-to-add-an-item-to-the-nautilus-right-click-menu) might be a decent place to start, if you're working with Gnome.

Comment: @nos, from context, it looks like that means "right mouse button [action]".

Comment: Yes, RMB == Right Mouse Button. Acronym my employer uses implying the popup menu that appears when pressing it, so used to it I didn't think to elaborate... @larsks currently running Cinnamon in Mint but I'm not married to it so if I need to move to try Nautilus I'm willing. I'll definitely give that link a go looks very promising.